# Typing a React component that wraps a native input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What's the right way to wrap a standard element as a custom component, keeping the correct interface/typing.

I got things working by copying the argument types from the element I was wrapping, but.. it's quite verbose.

Does TypeScript have a way to copy the argument types from another object?

```
const NumberInput = (props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const realInputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
    return (
        <div className="number-input">
            <button onClick={ () => realInputRef.current.stepDown() } className="minus"></button>
            <input  {...props} type="number" ref={realInputRef}></input>
            <button onClick={ () => realInputRef.current.stepUp() } className="plus"></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What about `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>`?

Comment: @raina77ow is that equivalent? I guess ideally I wouldn't need to specify it and could just say "whatever arguments this other thing takes"

Comment: Here's definition of [DetailedHTMLProps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1341): `type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E;` By this, the only thing that's added is `ref` property, which isn't usable for mimicking purposes anyway.

Comment: That's handy, thanks!

Comment: And to complete this, there's also a package [react-html-props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-props) that is basically a collection of prewritten aliases for all the types available.

Comment: I believe JSX.IntrinsicElements['input'] is what you're looking for.

Comment: @raina77ow thats.. exactly what I'm looking for! I'm guessing the existence of that package is a hint that there isn't a clever TypeScript trick that I'm missing..

Comment: Should I put this into answer?

Comment: @raina77ow sure go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how this generic type is defined in [Definitely Typed source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8bb11a2a03d668c2f464a492422922f609e3a4ab/types/react/index.d.ts#L1341):

```
type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E;
```

... where ClassAttributes interface seems to only add two properties to that - `key` and `ref`, both seem to not as useful for mimicking the native elements:

```
interface Attributes {
    key?: Key | null;
}

interface ClassAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
    ref?: LegacyRef<T>;
}
```

Another option available is using type definitions from in [react-html-props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-props) package, which is essentially a convenient open-source supported package of aliases. Its source code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

/** Equivalent to `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>` */
export type AProps = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>;

/** Equivalent to `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` */
export type APropsWithoutRef = React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>;
```

... and so on.